# Gradle task to create a zip archive

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I need to create a gradle task to create a zip where I need to include all the json files that contain text "type":"customer" how can i include the check for containing text ?
is there a way I can do it:

```
task createZip(type: Zip) {
    archiveName = "customer.zip"
    destinationDir = file(testDir)
    from(files(customer))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [FileTree](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileTree.html) together with Gradle/Groovy filtering capabilities:

Let's say you have your source Customer JSON files under `src/customers`: you can define a Task like that:

```
task createZip(type: Zip) {
    archiveName = "customer.zip"
    destinationDir = buildDir
    from fileTree('src/customers').filter { f -> f.text.contains('"type": "customer"')}
}
```

Note that this uses Groovy's [File.getText()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/1.8.6/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#getText(java.lang.String)) method to read the whole file content into memory to match the `"type": "customer"` expression. Be careful with performances if you have plenty or huge files to filter.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointer, new to gradle so was not knowing it.